# Migrating questions to "Programmers" at SE

Tags: discussion, software-engineering-se

I looooove StackOverflow so much that sometimes I ask questions there, that should be posted on other StackExchange site like Programmers, as for example this:

[Is there an industry standard for systems registered user permissions in terms of database model?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203360/is-there-an-industry-standard-for-systems-registered-user-permissions-in-terms-o)

What should I do, if I know that some of the people that I know are the most guru experts that I've ever seen are in SO but not at Programmers?

Is this kind of question not allowed in that site as well?

Answer (score 4):

The subject-matter experts will browse the sites that interest them in order to answer the types of questions that appeal to them. It is not acceptable to post a "Programmers" question on SO just to get the additional eyeballs.

However, if you can re-interpret your question to be code-related ("*In the absence of an industry standard, I attempted to implement foo like this, but it didn't work because bar*") you could post it on SO. You might even get an answer that contains pointers to the industry standard that you previously overlooked.

Comment: This is true.  I have experienced problems asking questions on SO related to better coding practices, when they should have been asked on CodeReview.  Reformatting the question in order to make it a good fit for SO is an interesting approach that I like.